# Bookshelf.js - hasOne relationship not working well

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I'm fairly new to bookshelf.js so please bear with me.

Since I'm learning, I'm using MySQL and have a really simple structure. Namely, two entities, with one secondary key. Here's my structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
  `people_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

ALTER TABLE `city`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`);

ALTER TABLE `people`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`people_id`), ADD KEY `city_id` (`city_id`);

ALTER TABLE `people`
ADD CONSTRAINT `people_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `city` (`city_id`);
```

And here's my code in expressjs, using bookshelf:

```
var City = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'city'
});

var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'people',
  city: function(){
    return this.hasOne(City, 'city_id');
  }
});
```

This is a sample code of how I run my query:

```
new User().where({people_id: req.params.id })
.city()
.fetch()
.then(function(user){
    res.send(user.toJSON());
})
.catch(function(error){
    res.send(error);
});
```

However, when I run the application, I get nothing but an empty json:

```
{}
```

I've enabled the debug mode in bookshelf, and this is the query it tries to execute:

```
 { __cid: '__cid1',
   method: 'select',
   options: undefined,
   bindings: [ undefined, 1 ],
   sql: 'select `city`.* from `city` where `city`.`city_id` = ? limit ?' }
```

Now as I've said it, I'm new to bookshelf. But this makes no sense; why doesn't it compare city.city_id to person.city_id (foreign key)?

Thank you for your time and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it working by doing the following:

1.) Rename the primary keys primary keys to `id`. The primary keys should be `city.id`, not `city.city_id`.

2.) Change the relation in the User definition to `return this.belongsTo(City);`

3.) You can access the city by doing `new User({id: 1}).fetch({ withRelated: ['city'] });`

Comment: How about without changing the schema?

Comment: You can define the primary key in the model if it is not 'id', using the idAttribute property: http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-idAttribute